# How to set background color to transparent for a richtextbox in c#

Tags: c#, transparent

I want to set the background color of the richtextbox to transparent In c#
can you help me please
Its a winform application

Comment: Transparent with respect to what?  There is a reason RichTextBox doesn't support transparency, and that's because it is difficult decide what to show behind it.  It can be anywhere in a component hierarchy.  For it to draw itself, then, it needs to know something about all the components up the tree.  You can hack it to be transparent all the way through the form, but you've not been clear about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That is not an option, not supported by the native Windows control.  It can be made to work on Windows 8 but that's not something you can count on today.  Windows 7 is the new XP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
    public class TransparentLabel : RichTextBox
    {
        public TransparentLabel()
        {
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, false);
            this.TextChanged += TransparentLabel_TextChanged;
            this.VScroll += TransparentLabel_TextChanged;
            this.HScroll += TransparentLabel_TextChanged;
        }

        void TransparentLabel_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ForceRefresh();
        }
        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams parms = base.CreateParams;
                parms.ExStyle |= 0x20;  // Turn on WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
                return parms;
            }
        }
        public void ForceRefresh()
        {
            this.UpdateStyles();
        }
    }
```

and the answer is look like this: 
[image]

Comment: It's work completely and perfectly. Just use this control

Comment: What is your mean?? Just a feature in c#, by setting the style in a control. What is your mean?

Comment: It doesn't do anything(i tested it).

Comment: Wait a minute. I have to put an image for this...

Comment: @valter the answer was a bit wrong, but now, it's OK. excuse me :)

Comment: And now try to change one of the Label's Text during runtime..

Comment: Can you please explain how to use this code ?

Comment: @TaW yes, it's true. i'm trying to solve this

Comment: @MuhammadNasirKhan the easiest way to this is: Drag a RichTextBox1 to form and go to the Form1.Designer.cs and replace the RichTextBox1 to TransparentLabel (don't forget the namespace)

Comment: @TaW the problem solved :)

Comment: Hardly. There simply is no real tranparency in Winforms Controls. Period. If you don't take my word, aks Hans or MSDN. It only can be faked.

Comment: @TaW Yes, The winForm basically dose not support the transparency background of control, but we can do some trick for this, like this that i'm mentioned before:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830079/how-to-make-the-background-of-a-label-transparent-in-c-sharp/25830214#25830214

Comment: The problem with this is that it will no update when things below change. Even if you notice and update that background image, the control on top will not notice it,; it only asks its parent once, upon creation, for the background its transparent parts are supposed to shine through. After that it'll show just that old image. To workaround that you'd have to delete and re-create the control..Not so much a workaround but a deep hack.

Comment: these just some **trick** not absolute answer...

Comment: Hm, I just played around a little and have to admit, it works better than I had expected. May well be good enough for the OP!

Comment: Try to move the *RichTextBox* and see what happens. No tranparency. Game over.